# No provider for Token FirebaseAppName

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I am facing a problem after upgrading Ionic and creating a new app and copying old working code to the new app.

Any help appreciated.

> ```
> Runtime Error
> Error in :0:0 caused by: No provider for Token FirebaseAppName!
> ```

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase(FIREBASE_CONFIG),
    Network,  FirebaseDataService]
```

info

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

Comment: are you using `angularfire2` or?

Comment: Yes, AngularFire2

Comment: where you have declared the firebase config details? can you show the code?

Comment: It looks like the new version of AngularFire2 requires the config to be defined in the imports and not providers. I followed the following steps, and this fixed my issue.  https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md

Comment: Hope you can put your own answer here.that will help for the Ionic2 community :)